# Finiteness for etale cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

The groups $H_{et}(X, \mathbb{Z}/n)$ are known to be finite for smooth projective variety over the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$. Are there finiteness/finite generation result for the etale cohomology of $\mathbb{G}_m$ and $\mu_n$ sheaves? ($n$ prime to characteristics)

Comment: I mean, this is a bit of vague question: "when are cohomology groups zero?" There are whole papers to studying this question in certain cases. Are you looking for a 'big list' of examples?

Comment: I was thinking more of general results rather than super specific $X$. For example is it true for a very general $X$ and for some choice of $n$ these become zero?

Comment: they are equal to singular cohomology for varieties over complex numbers so no there are not usually zero

Comment: at least the 2d-th cohomology is never zero because of pioncare duality which is true also in char p

Comment: Alright I changed problem to something different but similar.

Comment: When the base field is algebraically closed and $X$ is integral, then $(\mu_n)_X \cong (\mathbb{Z}/(n))_X$. We also have, under mild conditions, $H^1_{ét}(X,\mathbb{G}_m) \cong Pic(X)$, which is never finite (at least for projective varieties).

Comment: @Mindlack but I think $Pic(X)$ is at least a finitely generated abelian group for projective varieties which is good enough for many porpuses. But I don't know if it is true for higher cohomolgies of $G_m$ or not.

Comment: @ali: no, if $X$ is an abelian variety over an algebraically closed field $k$, then $Pic(X) \supset X^{\vee}(k)$ and $l: X^{\vee}(k) \rightarrow X^{\vee}(k)$ is onto (if $l \in \mathbb{Z} \cap k^{\times}$), so $Pic(X)$ isn’t finitely generated.